# verilog representation of a flops

Tags: verilog

I am teaching myself verilog and trying to write modelling a flop. I have come across the following modeling for ck->q delay arcs in specify section but could not understand what it exactly dos.

`(posedge CK => (Q : 1'b1))=(0, 0);`

Can anyone explain me on how it works? Is it like when `D=1, CK->Q` considers these delays?
if so Do we  need to have 
`(posedge CK => (Q : 1'b0))=(0, 0);`

Then what about X propagation on pin D

Answer (score 1):

Verliog can be used to model many levels. Simple **behavioural** model, **RTL** (synthesizable) modelling the transfer of data and control or **Gate level** which is at logic gate level, (ANDs ORs, Flip-Flops). Typically only Gate level has to be aware of these delays.

The typical way of modelling flip-flip behaviour in RTL is :

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  q <= d;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to *edge-sensitive paths*. According to [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) section 30.4.3, "it is used to model the timing of input-to-output delays, which only occur when a specified edge occurs at the source signal".

The data source expression (D=1'b1) in your example is an arbitrary expression, which serves as a description of the flow of data to the path destination. This arbitrary data path description does not affect the actual propagation of data or events through the model; how an event at the data path source propagates to the destination depends on the internal logic of the module.

In your case, `(posedge CK => (Q : 1'b1))=(0, 0)` or `(posedge CK => (Q : 1'b0))=(0, 0)` both mean at the positive edge of CK, a module path (aka delay arc) extends from CK to Q, which has rise and fall times of 0.